# Similarity of matrices and Smith normal form

Tags: matrices, smith-normal-form, similar-matrices

It is stated in the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form that $A \sim B$ iff SNF($xI-A$)=SNF($xI-B$).

How do you prove that?

Comment: Maybe in Hungerford's book or Dummit-Foote you can find the proof. Or even maybe is in Internet. Sorry if this comment isn't too helpdul

Comment: Off the top of my head, if the two Smith normal forms are equal, then the two $k[x]$-modules $k^n$ with $x$ acting as $A$ respectively $B$ should be isomorphic.  I would expect that if you express this isomorphism as an $n\times n$ matrix $P$ then that $P$ should be the matrix showing that $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Comment: You will find a detailed proof at Chapter 9 of Harold M. Edwards Linear Algebra.

Comment: cf. my answer in:        https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805325/smiths-normal-form-is-similar-to-xi-a/2824325#2824325